# How to move a JButton around using a timer

Tags: user-interface, animation, button, timer, jbutton

so I wanna have a button move around using absolute positioning via x,y coordinates and I have a white block moving with no image and isn't clickable

The image does work with the paint method using an image, but I wanna use a button

```
//********************************************************************
// ReboundPanel.java Java Foundations
//
// Represents the primary panel for the Rebound program.
//********************************************************************
package ch0;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ReboundPanel extends JPanel
{
 private final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 100;
 private final int DELAY = 20, IMAGE_SIZE = 35;
 private ImageIcon image;
 private Timer timer;
 private int x, y, moveX, moveY;
JButton button;

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 // Sets up the panel, including the timer for the animation.
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 public ReboundPanel()
 {
     this.setLayout(null); //Worked before I put this stuff but 
     super.setLayout(null);// I'm just trying stuff
 timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ReboundListener());
 image = new ImageIcon("smile.jpg");
 button = new JButton(image);
 button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("smile.jpg"));
 x = 0;
 y = 40;
 moveX = moveY = 3;
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
 setBackground(Color.black);
 timer.start();
 //button.setBounds(x, y, 10, 10);
 //add(button);
 }

//*****************************************************************
// Represents the action listener for the timer.
//*****************************************************************
private class ReboundListener implements ActionListener
{
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
// Updates the position of the image and possibly the direction
// of movement whenever the timer fires an action event.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
x += moveX;
y += moveY;
if (x <= 0 || x >= WIDTH-IMAGE_SIZE)
moveX = moveX * -1;
if (y <= 0 || y >= HEIGHT-IMAGE_SIZE)
moveY = moveY * -1;
button.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
add(button);
}
}
}

//********************************************************************
// Rebound.java Java Foundations
//
// Demonstrates an animation and the use of the Timer class.
//********************************************************************
package ch0;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Rebound
{
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 // Displays the main frame of the program.
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rebound");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.getContentPane().add(new ReboundPanel());
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true);

 }
}
```

Comment: apparently the image was too big